# R Importing Data for Time Series

Tags: r, time-series

Super new to R....I'm importing a one variable time series csv into R and when I run the summary it gives me a summary of the row numbers instead of the data. Can you tell me what I am missing? So appreciated!

```
data=read.table("CPI.txt", header = TRUE)
CPI=ts(data[,2], start=1956.4, frequency=4)
summary (CPI)

   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
    1.0    53.5   115.0   115.2   176.5   238.0
```

CPI.txt data is as follows:

```
DATE    CPI
10/1/56 14.88296727
1/1/57  15.02904093
4/1/57  .
7/1/57  .
10/1/57 .
1/1/58  .
4/1/58  15.37177038
7/1/58  .
10/1/58 .
1/1/59  .
4/1/59  .
7/1/59  .
10/1/59 .
1/1/60  15.61617193
4/1/60  15.57693532
7/1/60  15.55235335
10/1/60 15.63886299
1/1/61  15.66864499
4/1/61  15.71544529
7/1/61  15.81802776
10/1/61 15.8014822
1/1/62  15.82086414
4/1/62  16.07708395
7/1/62  15.99341069
10/1/62 15.99719254
1/1/63  16.18628465
1/1/00  16.20472113
1/2/00  16.31959458
10/1/63 16.55028696
1/1/64  16.72046986
4/1/64  16.85708891
7/1/64  17.14167253
10/1/64 17.26221875
1/1/65  17.40687422
4/1/65  17.6110937
7/1/65  17.78836755
10/1/65 17.93869578
1/1/66  18.17080634
4/1/66  18.51069941
7/1/66  18.44451717
10/1/66 18.57215435
1/1/67  18.68587719
4/1/67  18.84896018
7/1/67  18.99732891
10/1/67 19.17819162
1/1/68  19.26525096
4/1/68  19.35844124
7/1/68  19.48657788
10/1/68 19.64536921
1/1/69  19.87160087
4/1/69  20.08250519
7/1/69  20.25110602
10/1/69 20.46936747
1/1/70  20.72257526
4/1/70  20.90650345
7/1/70  21.04874124
10/1/70 21.14990174
1/1/71  21.44602612
4/1/71  21.72498386
7/1/71  22.01252492
10/1/71 22.28535172
1/1/72  22.56935891
4/1/72  22.80844264
7/1/72  23.21809221
10/1/72 23.63867549
1/1/73  24.12777667
4/1/73  24.45214333
7/1/73  24.7881726
10/1/73 25.28164726
1/1/74  26.16436191
```

Comment: Thank you for fixing the layout!

Comment: You're more likely to get an answer if you can provide some or all or `CPI.txt`; as plain text, or using `dput`, or as a link.

Comment: *"gives me a summary of the row numbers instead of the data"* What do you mean? `summary` does give you summary metrics based on the data! Compare with `summary(ts(10:20, frequency = 4, start = c(1959, 2)))`.

Comment: I'm hoping to find the summary of the data CPI and summary(CPI) is giving me the summary of the amount of rows in the csv as opposed to the data in the rows.

Comment: @neilfws ideally the data and code should be self-contained. Off-site resources are unpredictable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the .txt file uses "." to represent missing data.

Try it like this and it will work as expected

```
data=read.table("/tmp/CPI.txt", header = TRUE, na.strings = ".")

CPI=ts(data[,2], start=1956.4, frequency=4)
summary (CPI)
```

Using `na.strings = "."` ensures that missing values marked with "." are recognized as NA's, which allows the column to be imported as a numeric type instead of a factor.

Comment: YES! Thank you!!! My hero!

Comment: @user10227084 np! If the answer solved your issue, you may consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark next to it -it will be useful for future visitors to know that the solution was tested and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you used `read.table` without `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`. Since the `CPI` column contains non-numerical values (`.`), the column becomes a factor. `ts` then converts the values incorrectly.

So try this:

```
data = read.table("CPI.txt", 
                  header = TRUE, 
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
                  na.strings = ".")
```

Then run `str(data)` and check that column `CPI` is type numeric.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!